# self.socket.recv() wrong reading in adbclient.py while trying to run it on Python 3

Tags: android, sockets, python-3.x, porting, androidviewclient

I'm trying to run some `AndroidViewClient` example file (dump-simple.py) with Python 3.3

I fixed all essential syntax issues I could in viewclient.py and adbclient.py files to convert them run on Python 3.

I have Android tablet USB connected to my PC, I see it properly via cmd adb commands. I am working on Windows7 OS.

Currently I am facing the following problem:

In all the places `self.socket.recv()` function is used in adbclient.py file it returns `b''` string

I tried 4 different Andoid devices from 4 different vendors and `b''` was returned by `self.socket.recv()` for all of them.

What am I doing wrong, what did I still not converted to work with Python 3?

Comment: `b''` indicates that the socket connection is closed. Could this be?

Comment: Why not just running it with python 2.x?

Comment: User: Maybe. If so this caused by wrong (not ported) code. The device itself is connected and I communicate with it via cmd adb commands.

Comment: @dtmilano: Well, because python 2.x is old version, many bugs are fixed and many new important features are added in 3.x In addition I'm afraid that in the future 2.x will not be supported at all so I prefer writing all my files with 3.x from the very beginning. But if it is not possible I will start using 2.x